# ModalPopupExtender HTML scolling content

Tags: asp.net, html, modalpopupextender

I have been beating my head against the wall trying to figure out a way to do prevent the header row in my modal popup from scrolling, while allowing my content to scroll. My HTML is weak sauce but it seems that there must be a way to achieve this.

This is the basic look of the header.

```
 __________
|Header  |X| 
|________|_|
|Content   |
|          |
|          |
|          |
\__________/
```

Currently when the content overflows the container I get a scroll bar that scrolls the whole thing IE

```
 ____________
|Header  |X[^]
|________|_| |
|Content   | |
|          | |
|          | | 
|          |_|
\__________[v]
```

What I would like would be to have the scroll bar appear on the inside of the content block, and not scroll the header.

```
 __________
|Header  |X| 
|________|_|
|Content [^]
|        | |
|        | |
|        | |
\________[v]
```

This is the HTML for this modal control.

```
<input id="dummy" type="button" style="display: none" runat="server" />

<asp:ModalPopupExtender CancelControlID="Close" runat="server" ID="mpeThePopup" TargetControlID="dummy"
    PopupControlID="pnlModalPopUpPanel" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" PopupDragHandleControlID="Title" />
<asp:Panel ID="pnlModalPopUpPanel" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Width="1280px" Height="800px">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpInnerUpdatePanel" runat="Server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table id="ContentTableTag" runat="server" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;
                height: 100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td id="Title" runat="server" style="background-color: rgb(79,82,90); text-align: left;
                        height: 28px; width: 97%; color: White;" nowrap="nowrap">
                        <h4 style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px;">
                            <asp:Label ID="LblSectionTitle" runat="server" Text="Modal"></asp:Label>
                        </h4>
                    </td>
                    <td id="Close" runat="server" style="background-color: rgb(79,82,90); text-align: right;
                        height: 28px; width: 3%" nowrap="nowrap">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ibClose" runat="server" Style="margin-right: 5px;" ImageUrl="~/WLImages/MLS/button_close.png"
                            ToolTip="Close"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="standardFont" >
                    <td id="MainContentHolder" colspan="2" align="left" style="top: 0px; vertical-align: top; width: 100%; height: 100%" />
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea - try adding `overflow:scroll` in your maincontent area as so:

```
 <td id="MainContentHolder" colspan="2" align="left" 
        style="top: 0px; vertical-align: top; 
        width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow:scroll;"   
 />
```

Comment: So that seemed like it would work, but the scroll bars that are added by the above code remain greyed out, and the outer scroll bar is active, does not quite do the job.